# SQL Query having trouble creating temporary table

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I am trying to use the my table adult3 to create a temporary table with rows from the column class that correspond to the condition:

```
SELECT class INTO #CLTable
FROM adult3
WHERE (class = '<=50K');
```

but I keep getting the error :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>       'FROM adult3
>        WHERE (class = '<=50K')' at line 2

I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: U are using T-SQL way there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are using SQL Server syntax for creating a temp table.

Try this:

```
create temporary table CLTable as 
select class from adult3
where (class='<=50K');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
    INSERT INTO [tempTableName]
    SELECT class FROM adult3
    WHERE (class='<=50k')
```